# ArangoDB Foxx Service - Failed to load API definition

Tags: rest, api, web-services, arangodb, foxx

I am using arangoDB 3.3.3 on macOS.

With the intention to output a JSON-collection from arangoDB via the browser, i am using the Foxx microservice tool, which is offered by arangoDB. I imported the json-file to the database via the offered import script by arangoDB.

When I upload the service-file zip to the arangoDB web interface and trying to make a request to the linked path, it shows me the following error message in the API window:

Unauthorized http://localhost:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/foxxes/docs/swagger.json?mount=/getting-started

Anyone, facing the same problem and having an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in the web interface that should be fixed in 3.3.4, so updating should resolve your problem. See https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4453 for details.

Comment: Actually this error occured for the first time, when this bug for version 3.3.4 was available. But the bug didnt fix my problem so far.

Comment: If the bug persists, please add a comment in the github issue.

Comment: i think the bug wasnt the problem. I needed to give the service a new name, as the other used one was linked to an old path. Then it worked out.

Comment: I'm getting this error with all services with ArangoDB 3.4

Comment: Maybe my issue is different. New bug report here: Failed to load API definition. NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. · Issue #7892 · arangodb/arangodb https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/7892